# Error in aws patch manager for Ubuntu 22.x

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am getting below error when trying to patch Ubuntu server 22.x instance.

I am getting below error when trying to patch Ubuntu server 22.x instance.

/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/
jmespath/visitor.py:32: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if x is 0 or x is 1:
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:32: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if x is 0 or x is 1:
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:34: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
elif y is 0 or y is 1:
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:34: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
elif y is 0 or y is 1:
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:260: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?